# Can OpenCL trigger renders in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I have a complex iterative optimisation problem involving several steps. One of those steps involves taking the current iteration, and using values from it to render dozens of versions of a simple scene, then taking those renderings and performing some calculations on the pixels to create values which are then fed back into the optimisation algorithm. These steps are iterated many times.

This pseudo code illustrates roughly what I have in mind

```
array_A[100]
array_b[100]
fill array_A from CPU
Loop 100 times
{
    perform step 1 on array_A
    use values in array_A as angles to render 100 images of a cube with different rotations
    sum pixels in each image, and write results to array_B
    add array_B to array_A
}
Transfer array_A back to CPU
```

One way to do this would be to use the CPU to take information from OpenCL, use it to render all of these scenes, then Enqueue the kernels to process the renderings. However, a faster way must surely be to keep everything on the GPU, without involving the CPU.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Possible with "interop" between opencl and opengl.

Needed changes are:

- Query if `cl_khr_gl_sharing` is supported on device.
- Opencl Context needs to be queried and created with parameters that are intended for sharing with opengl. Such as `clGetGLContextInfoKHR` and `CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR,`. Needs handles of opengl context.
- Opencl buffers need to be created from opengl sources such as buffers, rendertargets and textures using `clCreateFromGLBuffer` and `clCreateFromGLTexture`
- Each transition between cl and gl(before sharing the shared buffer), synchronization points are needed. If opencl is computing first, finish it with `clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects` and `clFinish()`. Then opengl can take part, and when it finishes, `glFinish()` is needed before the `clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects` to get control of buffer for opencl again.

This way, if buffer is in gpu memory, it will stay in there. Only things reaching CPU will be synchronization and command messages, not data.

Opencl has events and event callbacks. You can register a callback function with `clSetEventCallback` so it will be faster than waiting for `clFinish()` because event waiting is also a synchronization point and is faster. Then you can redirect from callback to opengl api routines. Or just use clFinish simply and  put the opengl function after that. The fastest solution could be `GL_ARB_cl_event` to have gpu-side cl-to-gl event handling but I didn't try that.

```
array_A[100]
fill array_A from CPU
Loop 100 times
{
    compute on A with opencl
    clfinish
    cast shadows on A using opengl
    glfinish

}
Transfer array_A back to CPU
```

you can duplicate the A array for a double-buffering to be able to pipeline/overlap cl and gl calculations and get a whole lot faster.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But can OpenCL trigger a render in OpenGL, or can only the host do that?

Comment: `clCreateEventFromGLsyncKHR` if `cl_khr_gl_event ` is present so gl can trigger cl and `GL_ARB_cl_event` to trigger cl to gl but I didn't try those yet. They are not supported by all gpus.